# 720p videos on YouTube to 240p

Tags: youtube

When I start watching videos I change my video quality to 720p. But then, it changes itself to 240p. This problem had only cropped up recently, it did not happen to me last time.

Can a 10Mbps connection speed watch a 720p HD video on YouTube?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah a 10Mbps connection is sufficient to watch a 720p movie. It changes because HD isn't your default option.

1. Go to your [Settings](http://www.youtube.com/account_playback) page
2. Select Always play HD on fullscreen (when available)
3. Click the Save button